# Access a property record Values after deleting and updating

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, entity-framework-4

I have a database and I have created a wpf project with entity framework ,
after inserting a record in the database and save changes .
**The Question is :** 
If the user deletes  a record , I need to access that last  deleted record , 
and read its property values , and at updating operation i need to get old and new values to record properties being updating

Comment: Look at triggers. You can define distinct triggers for both insert and delete. This will allow you access to the deleted and inserted values.

Comment: I did that in the database , but i prefer to use sdf database , which does not have triggers

Comment: What is sdf database? You have tagged this with sql server so I assumed that is what you were using.